# I2C communication between arduino and raspberry pi breaks under stress for unclear reasons. Why?

Tags: i2c, raspberrypi, atmega2560

I am having a behavior I cannot explain while using arduino mega as a I2C slave for a raspberry pi master.

I am showing here an idealised program that shows the issue. I experience pretty much the same behavior in the real application (a keyboard firmware). What I am doing is the following:

- the arduino issues an interrupt on pin 23 at evert loop to inform the raspi that there's some data to be read.
- the raspi sends a request as master to the arduino.
- arduino receives the request in the Wire handler, and issues a reply of 32 bytes. I fill these 32 bytes with a uint8 counter just as a check.
- the cycle starts again.

This is the code for the raspi

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import smbus

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x42

def callback(channel):
    data = bus.read_i2c_block_data(address, 0x00, 32)
    print(data)

GPIO.add_event_detect(4, GPIO.RISING, callback=callback)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

and this is the code of the arduino

```
#include <Wire.h>

byte IRQ_PIN = 23;

volatile unsigned int counter;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);

    pinMode(IRQ_PIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(IRQ_PIN, LOW);
    Wire.begin(0x42);
    Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
    Wire.onReceive(receiveData);

}

void signalMaster() {
  noInterrupts();
  irq();
  interrupts();
}

void irq() {
  digitalWrite(IRQ_PIN, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IRQ_PIN, LOW);    
}

void requestEvent() {
  byte buf[32];
  counter++;
  memset(buf, counter, 32*sizeof(byte));
  Wire.write(buf, 32);
}

void receiveData(int byteCount){
  while(Wire.available()) {
    Wire.read();
  }
}

void loop() {
  signalMaster();
  delay(1);
}
```

As you can see, the point is that I am banging the I2C really, really fast, and the loop is very tight and fast. This is the point of the exercise and the problem to solve arises from this.

Now, once in a while I get an occasional IO error with the raspi python code. This code occasionally fails once, and then everything resumes to normal, but once in a while, it completely breaks down and never recover.

I attached a logic analyser to it, and this is what I found. D3 is the interrupt pin. The others the I2C bus. In a normal transaction, I can see everything working properly (disregard the different content of the response, it was an earlier run)

[image]

and a zoom in to the master request and the reply:

[image]

When I have a permanent failure, however, the picture is very different

[image]

Zoom in:

[image]

This makes little sense to me. Why would it perform a data write, and who is writing 0x85FF... in my buffer?

Thanks

Comment: The format is perfectly fine for an actual multi-byte write transaction. It's like the Python library is calling `write_i2c_block_data` instead of `read_i2c_block_data`. It must be some bug at the Raspberry end of things, possibly in the py-smbus library.

Comment: i'll do some debugging tonight.

Comment: @Majenko Ok, from a brief check of the current code, the smbus module is a direct call to i2c_smbus_access, which then just performs an ioctl... so if there's a bug, this goes quite deep. As a curiosity, could the fact that I am using 3.3v vs 5v be a factor? I read conflicting opinions on pairing arduino and raspi without a level shifter in the middle.

Comment: The voltage difference wouldn't cause the Pi to perform a completely different transaction.

Comment: It might be complete nonsense, but dissabling interupts on the arduino, than triggering the raspi, and than enabling the interupts sets the arduino in a state where it can not react on (now possible) I2C/SMBus interrupts.The raspi is really fast compared to the arduino and there might be a race condition. I admit; I do not believe in this solution myself, but if there no other solution it's worth a try ;-). How do you power/pull up the I2C bus. The resistors might be to high. Your Logic analyzers are no oscis. It shows you the logic levels not the real Voltages.  Th. might also be a problem.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer I am using an arduino mega 2560 which has internal resistors for the i2c bus. I have an osci as well, so I can give it a check. I must suspend the interrupts as I want to be sure that the interrupt pin is not kept high for a very long time if the ardu is disrupted.

Comment: If you power the I2C bus with the arduino than you use 5V (or is it a 3.3V Arduino?). That might destroy your raspi, please be careful with that. 
That's also an issue with the interupt PIN 5V is to high for the raspi it might tolerate that for a time, but it is a risk. You can use a voltage divider by two resistors.

Comment: The interrupt routines of the arduino should not run for a long time. And, as you react on the rising edge of the interrupt pin on the raspi , it is not a problem if the interrupt pin is high as long as you set it to LOW before the next interrupt. On the other hand, interrupts are necessary for IC2 to work. You could loose information if interrupts don't work, when the raspi started sending before enabling interrupts..

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer Excellent points. I'm going to rework a few things tomorrow evening and see what happens. When it comes to power, currently the arduino is powered via USB, and the raspi via a power supply. So yes, technically they are on different voltages. However, the idea is that both will be powered through the same 5V power supply. Of course the logic levels will not change regardless of the supply. Is a voltage divider resistor enough, or should I use a logic level converter? what is their physical difference?

Comment: The 5V from power supply are regulated to the operatng voltage of the Raspi. That's not the same. It's 3.3V.  See Bruno Bronosky's answer. 
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3209/what-are-the-min-max-voltage-current-values-the-gpio-pins-can-handle.

Comment: If your signal flows from the higher Voltage to the lower, a Resistor devider might be sufficient. If the signal goes to both directions highV <--> lowV you need a level shifter. If the signal flows from the lower to the higher Voltage and the device with the higher voltage interprets the high Level of the device with the lower Voltage as a high also, you can connect the device directly together if you be sure, that the higher Voltage device never put power on the wire.

Comment: What Raspberry are you using? It could be a clock stretchinh problem. I have it too with an Arduino project. If the slave is not able to answer, it try to stretch the clock signal. The Raspberry has some problems with it and once the sync clock is lost both devices will not work anymore... Until you reset the i2c line.

Comment: @adriano I am using a pi zero

Comment: Not sure, but I think that it is also affected by the clock stretching bug. Once the Arduino stretches the clock, the raspy will loose the synchronisation with your arduino.

Answer (score 2):

Use a logic level conversion IC.
[image]

picture source http://msx-elektronika.pl/en/logic-level-converter

Comment: I bought two, I'll give it a try this weekend

Comment: @StefanoBorini, results?

Comment: I added the logic level converter but I still get the same kind of errors. I am unsure at this point what is the reason. I decided that for the time being I just use a traditional keyboard microcontroller, but it's definitely something I have to revisit. I am adding a picture of my setup later tonight

Comment: @StefanoBorini, ok. I collected the half of the bounty and two upvotes, so if you now or in the future want to put a bounty on a question, write a comment here and I will put a 50 points bounty on that question (but only if I can't write a useful answer to it :-) )